# Is there a Swing JPanel toolbar background that fits all OSs?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, look-and-feel, paint

I'm using a JToolBar to have a toolbar on my application, but I don't like the look of it. Actually, there's basically no look, no background and the buttons are flat when the mouse is not over them. This is on Windows.

How can I have a better look for this? Something that would fit better on Windows? Maybe something like the ToolStrip in Visual Studio? Or maybe something better that would look much better depending on the OS version (Windows, Mac, Linux)?

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leverage the concept of [pluggable look and feels](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/ui/features/plaf.html) and select on each OS the look and feel considered native(or at least good looking) for it. The GTK+ look & feel look great in GNOME on Linux, Windows classic is for Windows pre Vista, etc.

Comment: I do that already... But I can't find a way to have a toolbar look like the ones on Windows.

Comment: The Windows Vista l&f looks pretty good, at least in my opinion. Nimbus looks great everywhere, but doesn't fit anyware. You might have a look at https://substance.dev.java.net/

Comment: Like I said, there's no background and the buttons are flat when the mouse is not over them. It doesn't even feel like a real toolbar. It's more like a bunch of buttons in a row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use existing libraries such as Ribbon component in [Flamingo](https://flamingo.dev.java.net/learn.html). If that is not what you want, the only choice you have is to create your own [ToolbarUI](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/ToolBarUI.html) implementation.